# Name of a class in OOP that has child classes but no parent classes?

Tags: oop

What is the 'official' name of a class in OOP that has child classes but no parent classes?

Is it a 'base class' or a 'root class' or something else?

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_class - a 'base class' is a class from which other classes have been derived. However, it is not clear if a base class in OOP can have parent classes.

Comment: In most languages, you cannot have such a thing, as all classes inherit from a system-provided base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually called a "root class," or more precisely, "root of the class hierarchy."

In almost all OO languages, there is only one such class. In Ruby, it is SimpleObject; in Java, Object. If a language allowed multiple parentless classes — i.e. didn't have an implicit "Object" parent class — I would hesitate to use the term "root."

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any particular "official" name.
The [MSDN page for System.Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx) simply states:

> Supports all classes in the .NET Framework class hierarchy and
>   provides low-level services to derived classes. This is the ultimate
>   base class of all classes in the .NET Framework; it is the root of the
>   type hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

A "base class", by definition, has no parent class. It's the superclass to all other classes.

For example, in Java, the `Object` class is the base class.

**[Edit]** It looks like there is no definite consensus on the question thus, and the current revision on Wikipedia states that "base class" is just another synonym for "superclass". So I guess there is no answer to your question, or multiple ones. Was it purely rhetorical or did you have a more precise question in mind ?

Comment: So, if class C extends class B and class B extends from class A, then isn't Class B a base class to Class C? Or if not, which would Class B be called? The wikipedia link seems to use 'parent' and 'base' interchangeably.

Comment: For me, in your example, B would not be a base class, but C's superclass (or parent class). I'm not completely agreeing with wikipedia here, but I assume it's one of these topics where there is no complete consensus yet...

Comment: What about something like root-branch-leaf? This convention seems to be used by oracle (http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/1012/tl_mappings/dscriptr36.html).

Comment: **Incorrect.** "Base class" is simply a synonym for "parent class." Wikipedia agrees: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_class#Subclasses_and_superclasses

Comment: @PaulCantrell Pretty much what I said in my comment. Included it in the answer for the sake of readability thus.

Comment: There most certainly _is_ a consensus. In ~20 years of OO programming, I've never heard anybody claim that "base class" means "root of the hierarchy." It is a synonym for parent or ancestor, period. In the first page of Google results on "base class," there are 7 instances where it means parent or ancestor, and only one about.com article of dubious provenance which uses it to mean root.

Comment: Interesting - the "base class = parent class" usage here is not that clearly put forward either in Google or in day-to-day IT business. Perhaps a mistranslation at some point, or a consensus that forked. I'll remember it when writing work documents aimed toward native English speakers.